# Pentaho Javascript step runs more times than intended

Tags: javascript, pentaho

I have a Pentaho `Modifed Javascript Value` step where I put this code and direct the output to a file:

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res1 = str.split(" ").length;
```

I feed the input to this step through a `Generate Rows` step with a dummy variable. In my output, I expect the result 5, but I get it printed multiple times like this:

```
tm_dummy;res1
;5
;5
;5
;5
;5
;5
;5
;5
;5
;5
```

Where `tmp_dummy` is the variable I declared in 'Generate Rows'
So why does it print '5' so many times? I use Kettle Spoon.

Comment: Because maybe loop? More code plz.

Comment: That is the whole code...

Comment: what is this `tm_dummy;res1` ?

Comment: res1 is the output of the javascript and tmp_dummy is a dummy variable...if you used pentaho, you will know a javascript step will not run until you feed it with some dummy input

Comment: Ok what is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is that i should have ;5 only once and not repeat it so many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have set `Limit` to 10 in `Generate Rows` step. If you need one make it 1.

Since it's 10 It will execute 10 times and it outputs 10 rows as you have posted.